# Error when trying to use a property for [(value)]

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to select that option field, which is stored in my database.

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(value)]="this.entities.gender" #gender formControlName="gender">
    <mat-option value="f">Female</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="m">Male</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
private entities: IprofileData;

async ngOnInit() {
  this.entities = await this.profileService.getEntities().pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
  console.log(this.entities); // <-- This returns all the data that I need
}
```

But I get the error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'gender' of undefined

Why am I not able to use `this.entities`?

---

### Update

I have also tried FormGroup to set the default value with

```js
  private profileFormGroup = this.fb.group({
    gender: this.entities.gender
  });
```

But I get the error

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'gender' of undefined

Comment: Have you tried the safe navigation operator? Like this: `this.entities?.gender`.

Comment: @R.Richards if I do this, I get the error *The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment*

Comment: Try just `entities.gender` No `this`.

Comment: @R.Richards I did but I still get the error *Cannot read property 'gender' of undefined*

Comment: Are you using [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) in your application? If so, you need to set the default value in the form group.

Comment: @R.Richards you're absolutely right and that would make more sense. I have tried it with `private profileFormGroup = this.fb.group({ gender: this.entities.gender})` but it throws the same error.

Comment: Where are you initializing formGroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use the `value` with `formControlName`, use `formControlName`

template

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select #gender formControlName="gender">
    <mat-option value="f">Female</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="m">Male</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

component.ts

```
private entities: IprofileData;

async ngOnInit() {
  this.entities = await 
  this.profileService.getEntities().pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
  console.log(this.entities); // <-- This returns all the data that I need
  // you need to put the value into formGroup
  this.profileFormGroup.get('gender').patchValue(this.entities.gender);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot use `this` in the template

Second, you cannot use `private` properties in the template, they must be public.

Third, I recommend you to stick with the observable instead of the promise, here is a better solution

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select [(value)]="entities$ | async as entities" #gender
      formControlName="entities?.gender">
    <mat-option value="f">Female</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="m">Male</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
entities$: Observable<IprofileData>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.entities$ = this.profileService.getEntities().pipe(take(1));
}
```

Comment: I get the error *Unexpected token 'as' at column 19 in [entities$ | async as entities]*. If I remove `as entities`, I get the error *Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 13 in [entities$ | async=$event]*